# intermitting Duplicate record in SQL database when SaveChanges() is called

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm wondering if anyone having the same issue.
I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 web application that create Purchase Orders and insert them in SQL database.
It has been working on all browsers(including Chrome) for years but lately it has been intermittently duplicating the insert record in SQL database whenever SaveChanges() is called only in Chrome(Safari/Edge are working properly).
I tried to check if the record exist in the database before the savechanges() is called but i guess it's duplicating the record the second savechanges() is called the first time.
Anybody else is experiencing this issue with Chrome?
I have logged this on the Chrome Forum as well as it feels like a bug in Chrome browser!!!!
Thanks in advance

Comment: Share your code. Your browser doesn't interact with your application's database, it's not a browser problem.

Comment: Why would the Chrome browser have ***anything at all*** to do with code that should exist on the server related to database manipulation?  Without seeing your code, there isn't any logical reason that this should be related at all.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, you absolutely right as i thought the same but testing wise tells me otherwise as whenever i use Edge or Safari I don't get the duplicate record only when i use Chrome.
Here is the bit of the code that make the duplicate when the id == 0 if yes then there will be duplicate record when using Chrome only. Thanks in advance
 if (o.Id == 0)
            {
                o.DateSubmitted = DateTime.Now;
                o.OrderNumber = db.OrdersTable.Max(s => s.OrderNumber) + 1;
                db.OrdersTable.Add(o);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }

Comment: Sorry if the code not enough but the comment was very short to share the whole of the function so I shared only the bit of the troubleshooting where the duplicate happens db.SaveChanges().

Comment: Hi again,
I just found this on the Chromium forum which is interesting so I'm reading through to see if it has the answer.
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=977882